# How to Check and Uncheck all the Legend elements in HighCharts Linechart?

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts, linechart

I want customize the checking and unchecking legend elements all at once, iam not getting any idea, can we do this? let me know way to do this..

Answer (score 17):

This is an example that does that, plus a variety of other things with legend items and checkboxes, using a series of external controls:

http://jsfiddle.net/simo/57SR9/94/

function:

```
$('#checkAll').click(function(){
    for(i=0; i < chart.series.length; i++) {
        if(chart.series[i].selected == false){
            chart.series[i].select();
            showSeries.call(chart.series[i], {checked: true});
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Nice demo. For the charts I already had (line or pie) the code with select and the showSeries method didn't work out of the box. My checkAll method looks like: `$('#checkAll').click(function(){  for(i=0; i < chartVarName.series.length; i++) {    if( chartVarName.series[i].visible == false){  chartVarName.series[i].show(); }}}); `

Basically using series.visible + show/hide instead of series.select().

Answer (score 1):

You can iterate over each series inside the chart and call `show()` or `hide()` function, depending on what you want to do. This solution is similar to the previous answers, but calling using the `show`/`hide` functions

```
i = 0;

while (i < chart.series.length) {
    if (chart.series[i].visible === false) { // here you can filter the visible series
        chart.series[i].select();
        chart.series[i].show(); // here you can call hide()
        i++;
        return;
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use something like this:

```
 var legendLeft = $j('<div>')
               .css({
                   width: 160,
                   maxHeight: 210,
                   padding: 10,
                   position: 'absolute',
                   overflow: 'auto',
                   right: 500,
                   top: 380,
                   borderRadius: options.borderRadius
               })
               .appendTo(chart.container);

           var legendRight = $j('<div>') .css({
                width: 260,
                maxHeight: 210,
                padding: 10,
                position: 'absolute',
                overflow: 'auto',
                right: 165,
                top: 383,
                borderRadius: options.borderRadius
           }).appendTo(chart.container);
```

Check this: http://highslide.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=9&t=15782

Example 1: http://jsfiddle.net/Fusher/ArmRM/14587/

Example 2: http://jsfiddle.net/hfrntt/EQGWV/